# Sudo user is not able to export path of ant

Tags: path, environment-variables, sudo, sudoers

Sudo user is not able to export path of ant.

I am trying to execute shell script `setpath.sh` which exports path for ant. After executing the script when I am executing ant command then getting ant command not found.

Here is my `setpath.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ABC_HOME=`pwd`
ANT_HOME=$ABC_HOME/lib/ant

PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$ABC_HOME/scripts/unix:$PATH

chmod +x $ANT_HOME/bin/ant
chmod +x $ABC_HOME/scripts/unix/*/*.sh

export ABC_HOME ANT_HOME PATH
```

Here are the steps I am using.

```
sudo -Hu abc /bin/sh setpath.sh
```

Note: I have placed alias of `. ./setpath.sh` command in sudo user's `.bash_profile`

```
alias setpath.sh='. ./setpath.sh'
```

So that I can use it in my command and script run in the current shell.

After executing script when I am executing ant command it is showing command not found.

I also checked ant_home and found it was not set even after executing `setpath.sh` script.

```
sudo -Hu abc echo $ANT_HOME
```

Getting ant_home as blank.

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Running a .sh script spawns a new shell. This shell is a child of your previous shell. Your script runs, then you are dropped back into the parent shell.

You cannot define the variables of a parent shell from its child shell. Sorry for the bad news.

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-16